# How can I get my Picker to vertically align in React Native?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have created a Snack here:

https://snack.expo.io/@deltanovember/dtest

using the libraries `react-native-easy-grid` and `native-base`.

I've created a basic table which appears as follows:

[image]

The far right column isn't properly vertically aligned because Score1 appears slightly above the rest of the row, whereas Score5 appears slightly below the rest of the row.

How do I get the far right column aligned with the rest of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns as a whole are vertically aligned. You should render row by row, because the data inside a row belongs together and the content of each column is not necessarily related to each other.

I've updated your code and created a snack. Check this out: https://snack.expo.io/@mukeyii/grid-vertical-alignment